# Rendering properties of class objects in VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

today I came across a problem. I have element in template which is set up like this:

```
<div v-if="object">{{ object.property }}</div>
```

It was constantly throwing an error which said
`cannot read properties of undefined reading 'property'`
I was so confused why there is an error like this when there is the v-if and in console it read properly. After that I realised that the object is an instance of class I've defined, it's not a normal js object. Can someone explain why Vue can't read properties of a class instance ?

Comment: There's no difference if it's class instance or plain object for this case. You ask about a wrong thing. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve if the problem persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most data properties in Vue have a value that will loosely equate to true unless it is a `primitive` value such as a number or a Boolean.

In your case what I resort to using is `v-if="'property' in object"`, this works as long as the value of `object` never starts as or becomes `null`, An initial value of an empty `object` is required.

```js
export default {

  data: () => ({
    object: {}
  }),

  beforeMount () {
    console.log('property' in this.object) // Logs false
  },

  mounted () {
    this.object = {
      property: 'some value'
    }
    console.log('property' in this.object) // Logs true
  }

}
```